# How do I find out if a given movie is available in Germany?

Tags: data-request, film, germany

Is it possible to check if a given movie, identified by its title or IMDb id, was either

- a) screened in German film theaters,
- b) shown on German TV, or
- c) distributed as DVD in Germany?

So far I am only aware of http://www.ffa.de/ which shows only the top 20 movies.

Comment: In the meantime I found 
this [Stackoverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api) which refers to [Rotten Tomatos](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/io-docs). Will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

The [IMDB data dump](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) contains theater release dates (warning, 46MB file):

```
ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/release-dates.list.gz
```

An example:

[image]

Unfortunately this is only cinema releases, and won't include TV showings or DVD releases. To get TV releases, the data source will probably be TV-specific.

Comment: Unfortunately the IMDB data is basically useless for most purposes: "The data can only be used for personal and non-commercial use and must not be altered/republished/resold/repurposed to create any kind of online/offline database of movie information (except for individual personal use)." (http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware)

Comment: @PatrickHoefler, Whether it's useful or not, That depends on where you live in.

Comment: @Pacerier would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @PatrickHoefler, Is there an **international** law stating you "must not be altered/republished/resold/repurposed to create any kind of online/offline database of movie information"?